# Webpack 1 + sass (in react) - leave my images alone

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass-loader

I have a project in React.js with SASS and using Webpack 1.

I have images folders with all the images and other assets' folders.

I do not want webpack to do anything with images, I want them to be loaded at the runtime by url.
I solved it in JSX by using image urls inline in the jsx code (rather then importing them) and it's working great.

But when I'm trying to do the same in SASS, it's different:
I used to refer to them in absolute pass /images/abc.png and it worked.
I didn't even had a webpack loader for them, it just worked.
But I had to change it to the relative path ../../www/images/abc.png and it's all broke down:
It refuses to work without webpack loader - just gives errors for each image.
I've tried using file-loader, but it copies all sass's used images into build folder.
I've tried using url-loader, but it just included the images into resulting css file making it enormously bloated.

So, what could I use to ignore the images from sass and just address them by url in the runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to set the [`url` option of the `css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#options-1) to false, so webpack won't touch the urls. Your rule for `.scss` could look something likes this (assuming you use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`):

Webpack 1:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false!sass-loader')
},
```

Webpack 2:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false } },
      { loader: 'sass-loader' }
    ]
  })
}
```

But that ignores all urls not just your images. If that is a problem you could use `file-loader` with the option `emitFile: false` so it won't copy your files. But you'll need some workaround to get the correct path. When using `[path]` in the name it will use the relative path from the [`context`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context). Because you're building it to a directory (e.g. `build/`) you'll need to go up one directory (`../`) by setting the `publicPath` option. Which would give you the following rule:

Webpack 1:

```
{
  test: /\.png/,
  loader: 'file-loader?emitFile=false&name=[path][name].[ext]&publicPath=../'
},
```

Webpack 2:

```
{
  test: /\.png/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    emitFile: false,
    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    publicPath: '../'
  }
}
```

If you've set `context` in your webpack config or your output CSS file is more than one level deep in the build directory, you'll need to tweak the `publicPath` option.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't help.
When I've tried the first option it still bloated my CSS to over 5Mb. When I've tried the second way, it still created many images with funny names in my build folder...
Btw, I'm using webpack1, maybe it's different, but I've adapted the options to Webpack1 way

Comment: Oh sorry I overlooked that, I changed the code to work with webpack 1. And if the first option still added inline data urls in CSS you probably have another `.scss` rule without `url=false` and it would  still use the `url-loader` for the `.png`. Make sure you only have one `.scss` rule, same goes for `.png` when using the second option. I've tested these configs with webpack 1 and they work as expected.

Comment: I've also edited your answer to return back your previous snippets for Webpack 2 for future reference, hope you don't mind. Thanks again for your help!